# Creat a circular ROI and account for partial pixel values

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I have a image of low resolution, 128x128 pixels. I need to obtain the mean value of a circle ROI, in order to do that I use the easy method:

```
%% Draw circle ROI 
t = 0:pi/500:2*pi;
xi = ((R0/pixelSize)*cos(t)+63.5+x0+((Rsphere)/pixelSize)*cos(theta))*4;
yi = ((R0/pixelSize)*sin(t)+63.5+y0+((Rsphere)/pixelSize)*sin(theta))*4;

%% Calculate roi statistics
line(xi,yi,'LineWidth',1,'Color',color);
ROImask = poly2mask(xi,yi, size(im,1),size(im,2));
ptROI = find(ROImask);
ROImean = mean(im(ptROI));
```

The problem here is that using this method I don't account for the partial value of a pixel in the ROI, as can be seen in the image.

Is there any direct way to obtain the mean of the ROI weighting the value of the pixels?

Thanks

[image: Artististic impression of the problem]

Comment: You could arbitrarily oversample the image to get a more fine-grained result, e.g. by doubling or quadrupling its size (i.e. one pixel becomes 2x2 or 4x4 pixels).

Comment: That was my first option, the problem is that near high gradients the `imresize` function generate some artifacts.

Comment: You would have to use nearest-neighbor interpolation, to prevent introducing "false" (interpolated) values. E.g. `imresize(I, 4.0, 'nearest')`.

Comment: Using the 'nearest' interpolation is not the same as not doing any resize? I though I should use at least a linear interpolation in order to account for partial pixel values.

Comment: Nearest-neighbor means taking the nearest pixel's value instead of an interpolated value calculated from multiple nearby pixels' values. It's imperative, in this case, **not** to use any other interpolation method for the upscaling, because each input pixel must be transformed to N equal output pixels of the same original value. Since every pixel represents the same amount of space, the duplicated output pixels must all have the same "weight" (value) when "voting for" (contributing to) the average you're calculating.

Comment: a different approach: blur the image such that a single pixel variation wont matter on the mean.

Comment: Have you figured out a solution yet? I'm curious as to how to solve this. If you haven't got a solution yet, I will try to work on it this weekend

Comment: @Swier although I would have liked an exact solution accounting for partial pixels, I ended doing a resize as suggested by  Norman

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this exactly, you'll need to do some calculus (integral of a circle on a square domain for each pixel). But, this probably overkill for your application. My suggestion is to calculate your circle on a fine grid, then resize it to match the image:

```
upFactor = 3;

% load built-in example image
x = imread('rice.png');

% convert to double
x = im2double(x);

% define the ROI
center = [68.5, 180]; % [row, column]
radius = 1; % pixels

% do the distance calculation
% (getting the coordinate systems to match is the hardest part, try making
% small examples to see how it works)
iVector = (0:size(x,1)*upFactor-1)/upFactor + .5 + 1/upFactor/2;
jVector = (0:size(x,2)*upFactor-1)/upFactor + .5 + 1/upFactor/2;
[I, J] = ndgrid( iVector - center(1), jVector - center(2));
sqDist = I.^2 + J.^2;
insideBig = double(sqDist <= radius^2); % need this to not be logical type

% this resizes back to the original image size my taking the mean of each
% upFactor by upFactor block
inside = reshape( mean( im2col( insideBig, [upFactor upFactor], 'distinct')), size(x));

% check that we have the values we expect
uniqueVals = unique(inside(:))

% show examples
figure
imagesc(x)

figure
imagesc(inside)

result =  sum(sum( x .* inside )) / sum(inside(:))
```